# Android Studio vs Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am new to android and I started development on Eclipse but it is creating lot of issues as Emulator is taking lot of time to start and in between it hangs aswell.

Just now learnt there is another tool "Android Studio". Can I use android studie instead of eclipse? are there any performance issues with android studio.

Please anyone suggest me to clear the confusion. I am ready to shift to android studio if it is more user friendly than eclipse.

Thanks
Siva

Comment: If your issue is only with the Emulator, just connect an android phone to the computer via USB and test the app on that device straight from Eclipse.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a lot of info on both if you googled it. But the only way you'll know for sure is if you try it yourself and see what's better for you.

The emulator though will be the same for both platforms, so if the emulator is what's bugging you there won't be any improvement. For a faster emulator take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator).

Also remember that Android Studio is still only in preview so there are lots of bugs that are being resolved every day. This video is a good preview of what to expect from Android Studio (now and in the future):
https://developers.google.com/live/shows/478404424

Answer (score 12):

For beginners, I think that Eclipse is a lot easier to start with. But with development, Android Studio is a lot faster, ie in designing User Interfaces, it is a lot faster since it gives you a better preview of your layout on different devices without having to launch it on an emulator.

Comment: Thanks msana... your input has provided me some insight.

Answer (score 9):

Android Studio is based on community version of IntelliJ IDEA and is currently in development. It has new build system based on Gradle. Eclipse is good but the future is Android Studio.

Comment: I think the build is based on Gradle (not Groovy)