# Should I get into Android Studio or should i stick to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, android-studio

I started programming a few months ago, and learned python and I started learning Java about a month ago.

I've been using sublime text for coding Java programs, and now as I am getting into Android Programming, I found two official IDEs --> Eclipse and Android Studio.

After two hours of research, I've learned a few things: Android studio is an early preview, and it is not recommended for beginners.

However, Android Studio shows so much promise that I think it will be taking over eclipse in the next few years, assuming that google will publish an official polished version in early 2014.

I have nothing against Eclipse, but it just seems like Android Studio is the way to go if I'm looking to program Android apps 5+ years later.

What are you guys' opinion on it?

I know the basic idea of how android programming works, including xml, and wanted some recommendation on whether I should get into Android Studio or not.

As Android Studio is a rolling release, it's not like I would have to start all over when new versions come out, so I think updating versions is not a problem

So, will it benefit me in the future if I get into using Android Studio rather than sticking to traditional Eclipse with Android sdk?

Need some answers from experienced developers who use/used Eclipse and have tried Android Studio.

Thanks

Comment: On my experience, Eclipse is unstable. Android Studio, a little complex, still under Preview.

Comment: Unstable how? Plugins crash it? Same here, but I'm not entirely sure that's Eclipse's fault.

Comment: for me eclipse crashes once per week and it was more unstable because of 3rd party plugins before, which i removed

Comment: Somewhat related...I have written up a comprehensive overview of the differences between Android Studio & Eclipse for people who are wondering what is involved in switching: http://www.airpair.com/android/android-studio-vs-eclipse

Answer (score 5):

It is a matter of personal preference. I have used android studio and eclipse and also used sublime text for android programming. For starters eclipse is the best(my view). Android Studio is great too(layout support) but you should know that it is in preview as of now. Honestly I suggest using eclipse for a while then after you gain some experience switch to android studio. Also visit the following links:
[Android studio vs ecllipse](http://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/android-studio-vs-eclipse-1-0)

[This one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055900/android-studio-vs-eclipse-ide)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you shouldn't need either - I knew someone that used text editor and compile from command line, that is basically what Eclipse/Studio are doing, but with some clever UI design tools, and a "run" button instead of setting up and running an ant build.

I would tend to prefer Eclipse, since it can be used for many other things than Java/Android, has a large following, and is mature with very good Android tools, right now. I doubt that will change soon.

Answer (score 0):

Can't give a exact answer for this. I like to deal with Eclipse. Another one may like to deal with Android Studio. It is vary with different developers. If Eclipse makes you comfortable with coding, use Eclipse. If Android Studio makes you comfortable with coding, use  Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would like to continue with eclipse due to years of practice on it! Yes, but you can surely try to use Android studio where you are not working on critical projects cz you don't have time to search for things regarding adt again and again until you are comfortable!

Answer (score 0):

```
 well i figure out this from this content you must read as well
```

Working with eclipse can be difficult at times, probably when debugging and designing layouts Eclipse sometimes get stuck and we have to restart eclipse from time to time. Also you get problems with emulators.

Android studio was releases very recently and this IDE is not yet heavily used by developers. Therefor it may contain certain bugs.

This describes the difference between android android studio and eclipse project structure:
[Android Studio Project Structure (v.s. Eclipse Project Structure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431838/android-studio-project-structure-v-s-eclipse-project-structure)
This teaches you how to use the android studio:
http://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/android-studio-vs-eclipse-1-0